# C# project does not see Excel COM Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, reference, automation

im writing an application using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition. I have a problem using Excel Automation. I added a COM Reference to Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. It added following References:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 
VBIDE
```

I also added a using clause:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then i took a code snippet from [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023):

```
m_objExcel = new Excel.Application();
m_objBooks = (Excel.Workbooks)m_objExcel.Workbooks;
m_objBook = (Excel._Workbook)(m_objBooks.Add(m_objOpt));
```

and it underlines Excel and shouts:

> The type or namespace name 'Excel'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have Office 2007 Professional Plus and the *"Interoperability component for .net 2.0 Microsoft Forms"* (sorry, translation from polish) installed. Target Framework is .NET 4 Client Profile.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing your `using` to:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

That way `Excel` will be an alias for the full namespace, which the rest of the code seems to expect.

Comment: I wonder how many thousand people have been confused this little problem when reading online examples!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this... using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; (as found from [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm))