# Excel.dll- Getting error on using Excel

Tags: c#, excel, dll

I am using `Excel.dll` in my project to access data from Excel file.
I have already added Excel.dll in Bin folder of my website.
In my webpage i used using directive:

```
using Excel;
```

and code is

```
String path = "F:\\Saurabh\\database\\FMData1.xls";
FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;       
excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
```

In my local server it is running fine.
But when I uploaded it to the server it is giving error.

```
The type or namespace name 'Excel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I think there is some problem with the .Net framework.
Please help.......

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the .NET Framework. You get the error because somehow the reference to the dll is missing/not working.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/4386968/1241400 but really don't use Interop. Check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692092/A-free-Export-to-Excel-Csharp-class-using-OpenXML or https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# project does not see Excel COM Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386922/c-sharp-project-does-not-see-excel-com-reference)

Comment: plurby, theghostofc it is not helpful

Comment: If you are using Excel.dll it does not necessarily mean that the namespace will be Excel. Look at the documentation for Excel.dll.

Comment: If namespace is not correct then how it is working in my local server.

Comment: Do you mean *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll*, or do you just have a random DLL called *Excel.dll*, and are asking us why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing wrong with the code, dll or using directive, the problem was that i placed my Bin folder at wrong place. I placed it at the root directory and now it is working very fine.
Thanks to all, for giving your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `using` to:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

[Please Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386922/c-sharp-project-does-not-see-excel-com-reference/4386968#4386968)